# Is there any way to force Sitecore CMS users to change their password on the first login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I'm using Sitecore 8.2 update 5 and would like to make a functionality that force CMS users to change their password on the first login. Could you please advise me on what and where I need to do to meet that requirement? I made some researches, however this is incompatible with the current version.

Answer (score 1):

There is no functionality in a default installation of Sitecore that would do what you are trying to do. You would need to implement your own code to accommodate for this. There is an event in Sitecore called `security:loggedIn` that you can add a handler for to check if the logged in user is a new user, and if so, redirect them to a Change Password page for the user to change their password.